# Actionscript/Flex string to array

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I'm working with a 3rd party web service and it's returning a string like the below. I'm completely stuck on how to parse this into a usable format. It appears it's an array, just in text format.

```
[["theData",{"something":somevalue,"details":null,"somethingElse":"something"},0]]
```

It could also have multiple, like

```
[["theData",{"something":somevalue,"details":null,"somethingElse":"something"},0],["theData",{"something":somevalue,"details":null,"somethingElse":"something"},0]]
```

I've tried setting the HTTPService result type as array/arraycollection, that doesn't work. The only thing I can think is to do some sort of string split/join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like JSON to me; so I would look into using the Flash Player's [native JSON](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html) classes.

If you really want to use String parsing; then I'd look into the [split()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#split%28%29) function; which will turn it into an Array.  But, it seems like you'd be stuck doing string parsing to get every value.

Comment: Yes, JSON is the {} part, which is part of the array.

Comment: You were correct. It was JSON. (facepalm). I'm so used to an array of json starting/ending with {}

Comment: @beta4 No need to facepalm.  Four months ago I wouldn't have recolonized it at all.